# Big Data Hive Query

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have the below data

```
Policy_Name  IssueYear   ExpiryYear
A            2001        2003
B            2003        2006
```

I need the output like below :

```
Policy_Name ActiveYear
A           2001
A           2002
A           2003
B           2003
B           2004 
B           2005
B           2006
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  t.Policy_Name 
       ,t.IssueYear + pe.i  as ActiveYear

from    mytable t
        lateral view posexplode (split (space (ExpiryYear - IssueYear),' ')) pe as i,x
;
```

---

```
+---------------+------------+
| t.policy_name | activeyear |
+---------------+------------+
| A             |       2001 |
| A             |       2002 |
| A             |       2003 |
| B             |       2003 |
| B             |       2004 |
| B             |       2005 |
| B             |       2006 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: Very Elegant  +1

Comment: Thanks Dudu. Its simply outstanding.